# Check the request headers with url2lib

Tags: python, http-headers, urllib2

I am trying to fetch a page with Python, and using the cookie jar.

```
jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)')]
response = opener.open('http://www.example.com/')
print response.info()
```

Using the above, I can get the response headers, but other than WireShark, can I see the request headers? What urllib2 was sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, though [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#examples) indicate that there isn't much added. You could setup an [http server in python](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html), send the request to it first, pull out the headers, and then check those. But if you have wireshark, it's less work to just use that.